# error: Segmentation Fault al trabajar con vectores

Tags: c++

Me ha surgido un problema que me impide continuar en mi proyecto para la universidad. Obtengo el siguiente error tras compilar y ejecutar y llegar a la segunda función:

```
bash:
Vamos a comparar el tiempo de operación de estos cuatro contenedores: 

 -> VECTOR
 -> LIST
 -> SET
 -> UNORDERED_SET

Inserte el número máximo de elementos para los contenedores: 
999
TEST INSERCION VECTOR
Creando un vector de 999 elementos...
TEST BORRADO VECTOR
./ejecutame.sh: line 10: 26414 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./ejecutable
mv: cannot stat '/*.o': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '/*.txt': No such file or directory
```

Este es el fragmento del código:

```
void vector_borrar(int elementos){
    int counter = 0;
    ofstream file;
    file.open("vector_borrar.txt", ios::out);
    if(file.fail()){
        cout << "El archivo <<vector_borrar>> no ha podido ser creado" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<elementos; i++){


        vector<int>test2;

        for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
            test2.push_back(i);
        }
        auto mid = std::next(test2.begin(), test2.size()/2);
        auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
        test2.erase(mid);
        auto end = chrono::system_clock::now();
        chrono::duration<double>elapsed = end - start;
        file << i << ";" << elapsed.count() << endl;

        test2.clear();
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Aquí está todo el archivo

[Programa](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y4bLPn5mivq4Dmf315gJHP_E7Q7SdFOS?usp=sharing)

Creo no haber accedido a zonas de memoria que no debiera.

Answer (score 1):

Sin contexto es difícil ver el error. Por ejemplo: no veo en el código que compartes dónde imprimes el mensaje `TEST BORRADO VECTOR` previo al fallo.

Lo que sí que veo es que borras desde un iterador incorrecto, lo cuál es un error:

```
for(int i=0; i<elementos; i++){


    vector<int>test2;

    // En la primera vuelta del bucle que indiza sobre 'i', el índice es 0
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
        test2.push_back(i);
    }

    // vector::size es 0, porque no se ha añadido nada
    auto mid = std::next(test2.begin(), test2.size()/2);

    // …

    // 'mid' apunta a un iterador que equivale a end
    test2.erase(mid);

    // …
}
```

Dado que en la primera vuelta del bucle principal, le índice `i` vale cero, al llegar al bucle anidado que rellena datos, no añades ningún dato. En un contenedor vacío los iteradores *begin* y *end* son el mismo (y dado que no tienes datos `test2.size()` es cero y avanzas *begin* cero posiciones).

Para que un iterador sea borrable, debe ser des-referenciable, [según la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) (traducción mía):

> El iterador debe ser válido y desreferenciable. Por lo tanto el iterador `end()` (que es válido, pero no es desreferenciable) no puede ser usado.

La documentación también indica que el primer iterador es borrable, pero si el contenedor está vacío se traduce en una [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) (traducción mía).

> El iterador `first` no necesita ser desreferenciable si `first==last`: borrar un rango vacío es una NOP.

Sin embargo todas las pruebas que he hecho de borrar el iterador `begin` de un contenedor vacío me dan el fallo que estás experimentando.